# Using a calculation and a string in an input. (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, string, input, python-2.7

I'm having this annoying problem in Python 2.7, it won't let me do this

```
numbers = raw_input(numbers + 1 + ': ')
```

I want it to print out 'numbers + 1' as a number in the console but..
It comes up with this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/Python/Conversation", line 25, in <module>
    numbers = raw_input(numbers + 1 + ': ')
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Is there a solution or just another thing that I can use instead of this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message points out, you cannot add a number and a string. You *can* add two strings, so try this:

```
raw_input( str(numbers+1) + ':' )
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to put `+` and `numbers` inside a single/double quote; or else, it will be treated as a string concatenation. You got the error because you tried to concatenate/add `numbers` with `1`.

So, you need to cast `1` to a string, using [str( )](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str). Then, concatenate it with `'numbers + '` and `':`'. Like so:

```
>>> numbers = raw_input('numbers + ' + str(1) + ': ')
numbers + 1:
```

**However**, If you want to replace `numbers` with number:

```
>>> numbers = 3
>>> numbers = raw_input(str(numbers + 1) + ': ')
4:
```

It works because you add the `numbers`'s value with `1` first. Then, cast the result to string later.

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn the `1` int value into a string:

```
numbers = raw_input(numbers + str(1) + ': ')
```

Alternatively, use string formatting:

```
numbers = raw_input('{}{}: '.format(numbers, 1))
```

Or perhaps you wanted to turn *`numbers`* into an `int` first, then the *result* into a string:

```
sum = int(numbers) + 1
numbers = raw_input(str(sum) + ': ')
```

Comment: if numbers is initialised as 6, it prints 61.. So this doesn't give the correct output

Comment: @Aswin: Which *could* have been what the OP wanted. In any case, my last guess turned out to be the correct one.

Comment: OP wanter it to be `numbers+1` (ie) if numbers is 5, it should print 6

Comment: @Aswin: We probably have to agree to disagree here, but the question was ambiguous. There are several *different* answers here now, for instance.